# android studio post request volley not returning search

Tags: java, php, json, post, android-studio

I am searching my database for music, i have done the same in swift ios without any trouble. However when i try the same in java i am just getting my complete table and not just the tracks i am searching for. I am pretty new to android studio and java. I m using volley and i can't find the problem. seems things are not getting posted correctly or received corrected by php. Thing that really has me puzzled is that when i try to query the database in the browser i am also getting a faulty out put. When i try to do this from the ios app i'm getting the correct out put and it has searched the database correctly.

This is my android code

```
private void searchsong() {

        String submitUrl = SEARCH_SONG_URL+"?searchWord="+searchWord;

        Log.d("search song Json url", submitUrl);

        JsonArrayRequest req2 = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, submitUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                            // update the data in your custom method.
                            mJSONAdapter.updateData(response);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Log.d("Submitting searchword", searchWord);

                    params.put("searchWord", searchWord);

                Log.v("Params", "" + params);

                return params;


            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(req2);
    }
```

The following is the php code i am using. It is very easy. Also it is not working when i wrap in a S_post tag

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
//if($_POST) {


    $searchWord = $_POST['searchWord']; 


  //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("$host","$db_user","$db_password","$db_name") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE track_name LIKE "' . $searchWord . '%"' . 'OR artist LIKE "% ' . $searchWord . '%"'. 'OR tags LIKE "% ' . $searchWord . '%"'; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array

    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);


//}/*end if POST*/

?>
```

It seems like my android code is not posting to the php file, but when i look at the logcat it shows a url that says php?searchWord=..... i am totally lost as to what i am doing wrong. I've build a login script that check the user credentials and it works just fine. I am puzzled about why this isn't working.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

you don't send post params as you expect them. 2 solutions:

1) Change the request to GET

here

> JsonArrayRequest req2 = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
>   submitUrl,

and here

> $searchWord = $_POST['searchWord'];

and you can remove this:

```
> @Override
>             protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
>                 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
> 
>                     Log.d("Submitting searchword", searchWord);
> 
>                     params.put("searchWord", searchWord);
> 
>                 Log.v("Params", "" + params);
> 
>                 return params;
> 
> 
>             }
```

Option 2: Use POST but send as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

override this in your request:

```
  public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=" + getParamsEncoding();
    }
    /**
     * Returns the raw POST or PUT body to be sent.
     *
     * <p>By default, the body consists of the request parameters in
     * application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. When overriding this method, consider overriding
     * {@link #getBodyContentType()} as well to match the new body format.
     *
     * @throws AuthFailureError in the event of auth failure
     */
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = getParams();
        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
        }
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * Converts <code>params</code> into an application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded string.
     */
    private byte[] encodeParameters(Map<String, String> params, String paramsEncoding) {
        StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('=');
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('&');
            }
            return encodedParams.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
        }
    }
```